# switch between two databases for different users in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to change the database name in database.php passing value from the controller. I tried sessions and env variable. but in the database.php cannot access the value from sessions and env variable. also, i need to use the default database to load the page and when user has been logged in need to switch the database. i'm doing this for reducing size of the database data is there any solution really glad someone can help me.

**databse.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


if($db_val==""){
    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'sliate_srs',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt'  => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
}
else{

    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => getenv("DB_year"),
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt'  => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
}
```

**controller.php**
function loginSubmit() {

```
   $DB_year=$this->input->post('year_select'); 
    //$this->session->unset_userdata('DB_year');
  
    

    
    //$this->session->set_userdata('DB_year',$DB_year);
    $DB_year="srs_2019";
    putenv("DB_year=$DB_year");
    // $_ENV["DB_year"]="srs_2019";
    print_r(getenv("DB_year"));
    // $DB_year="srs_2019";
    

   
    $result = $this->Login_model->authenticateLogin(); 
    
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
        $data = array(
            'u_id' => $this->session->userdata('u_id'),
            'u_name' => $this->session->userdata('u_name'),
            'center_name' => $this->session->userdata('u_branch'),
            'last_login_ip' => $this->input->ip_address('ip'),
            'last_login_date_time' => $now
        );
        $name = $this->session->userdata('DB_year');
        print_r($name);
        $this->Login_model->last_login($data);
        redirect('Admin/dashboard');
    } else {
    
        redirect('Login?login=invalid');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `i'm doing this for reducing size of the database data`...why, how much data have you got? What problem is it causing you exactly? On modern harware, unless you have got dozens of GB of data and/or a badly-designed database then you're unlikely to have any practical problems. This sounds like potentially a case of premature optimisation, and/or an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please clarify the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the config group in Database.php, why not create a custom connection in your model, as explained in [Connecting with Custom Settings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html?highlight=database#connecting-with-custom-settings)?

Comment: i found the way to do that need to change systems/core/Model class CI_Model public function __construct()
 {
  log_message('info', 'Model Class Initialized');

  if(isset($_SESSION['DB_year']))
  {
   $this->db=$this->load->database($_SESSION['DB_year'], TRUE);
  }
 }

Comment: Very bad idea changing core files.  
As soon as you update CodeIgniter, you'll loose your changes